# Combinar duplicadas no R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

Estou querendo combinar os valores duplicados no R, por exemplo, tenho a tabela abaixo:

```
V1   v2         v3          v4  v5  v6
1 229567934 rs1416312998     T  G   ACTA1
1 229567934 rs1416312998     T  G   ACTA1
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADAM15
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADAM15
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADC
```

e quero que ela fique assim:

```
V1   v2         v3          v4  v5       v6
1 229567934 rs1416312998     T  G   ACTA1,ACTA1
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADAM15,ADAM15,ADC
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### R base

Aqui vai uma solução R base em uma linha.

```
aggregate(v6 ~ ., df1, c)
#  V1        v2           v3 v4 v5                  v6
#1  1 155033913  rs138833444 CG  C ADAM15, ADAM15, ADC
#2  1 229567934 rs1416312998  T  G        ACTA1, ACTA1
```

---

### Solução `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(V1, v2, v3, v4, v5) %>%
  summarise(v6 = paste(v6, collapse = ","), .groups = "drop")
## A tibble: 2 x 6
#     V1        v2 v3           v4    v5    v6               
#  <int>     <int> <chr>        <chr> <chr> <chr>            
#1     1 155033913 rs138833444  CG    C     ADAM15,ADAM15,ADC
#2     1 229567934 rs1416312998 T     G     ACTA1,ACTA1
```

### Dados

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
V1   v2         v3          v4  v5  v6
1 229567934 rs1416312998     T  G   ACTA1
1 229567934 rs1416312998     T  G   ACTA1
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADAM15
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADAM15
1 155033913 rs138833444      CG C   ADC
", header = TRUE)
```